# Angular 10.1.1 How to Make Multiple URLS

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make it when I go to myurl.com/create it opens the component I made. This is my first time using Angular and cant figure it out. Here's the Code I have. When I do `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` if I change my HTML code to `<h1>Hello</h1>` it will show up underneath what I have there from my root component. I don't know what else to do here. I have this assignment due for school and I'm using languages that I've never delved deep with before.

```
//app-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { RoundRobin, Title } from './app.component';
import { createAccount} from './create-account/create-account.component'

import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'create', component: createAccount},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RoundRobin,
    createAccount
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    
    MatIconModule,
    
   
    MatRadioModule,
    MatGridListModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
    createAccount,
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    RoundRobin,
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export class AppModule { }
```

```
//create-account.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'CreateAccount',
    template: './create-account.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-account.component.css']
})

export class createAccount{

  hide = true;

}
```

```
//create-account.component.html

<html>
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="500px">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <div class="example-container">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-50">
        <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-50 ml-2">
        <mat-label>Surname</mat-label>
        <input matInput>
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100">
        <mat-label>Email address</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com">
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100">
        <mat-label>Enter password</mat-label>
        <input matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
        <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
          [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
          <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <label id="example-radio-group-label">Gender: </label>
      <br><br>
      <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">Male</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value="2">Female</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value="3">Custom</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
      <br><br>
      <label id="example-radio-group-label">Date of birth: </label>
      <br><br>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-25">
        <mat-label>Day</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
          <mat-option [value]="6">
            26
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-25 ml-1">
        <mat-label>Month</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
          <mat-option [value]="6">
            26
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-25 ml-1">
        <mat-label>Year</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
          <mat-option [value]="6">
            26
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the best result, you would better use the **angular cli**. Below steps will give you a clean working code

- In your projects folder, run `npm install -g @angular/cli`. This installs angular. You only need to run this once. You will need npm [Download node](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)
- If above step runs successfully run `ng new my-project-app --routing`. Note the `--routing` flag
- Inside **my-project-app** folder created by the CLI, run `ng generate component create-account` **OR** `ng g c create-account`
- Now run `ng serve`. This should run without any problems and your app can be viewed at http://localhost:4200
- Now in your **app-routing-module.ts** file change the line `const routes: Routes = []` to the below. Ensure to import the component

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'create', component: CreateAccountComponent },
];
```

- Now edit **app-component.html** to

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

- Now try to visit http://localhost:4200/create. This should display

> **Hello** 
> create-account-works!

- With the cli, angular names all our files as per convention e.g `createAccount` will actually be `CreateAccountComponent`
- When everything works, you can now replace the content of `create-account.component.ts` and `create-account.component.html` with your code
- Final note: Remove the `<html>` tag in you template file. This is not required here

Check this simple [Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ndddpx)